# can you foreach two arrays at once?

Tags: php, sql

```
foreach (($_POST['pedimento'] as $value) && ($_POST['observacion'] as $obs))
{
    $sql1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO pedimento (`error`,`observacion`) VALUES ('$value','$obs')");
}
```

im trying to insert data from two arrays, does anyone know how can i get the data from the two arrays simultaneously, and save them together in one sql statement?

Comment: Don't think it can be done like this. Still it would be helpful if you can post code of what you have tried so far, what exactly is not working and what do you expect the output/end result to be.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Do not use `$_POST` values in a query like this!  Move to prepared statements using PDO or MySQLi.**

The only way this makes sense as the other answers assume, is if the arrays are the same length and have identical keys so:

```
foreach ($_POST['pedimento'] as $key => $value)
{
    $obs = $_POST['observacion'][$key];
    $sql1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pedimento (`error`,`observacion`)
                         VALUES ('$value','$obs')");
}
```

Comment: lol, I was trying to solve this but never worked for me, but now it works great !, thanks AbraCadaver! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would turn your foreach into a for loop with an int counter:

```
for($i = 0; $i < array.length; $i++)
{
    $x = arrayOne[$i];
    $y = arrayTwo[$i];

    $sql1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO pedimento (error,observacion) VALUES ('$x','$y')"); }
}
```

PHP isn't my strong suit (not by a long shot) but I checked that For loops work.  As long as array logic works even remotely like other languages, the above statement should loop through both arrays (assuming they are the same length) and create an INSERT statement with the two values it finds.

Comment: Just ensure that $i never goes outside of the bounds of the array.

Comment: Sorry, as I mentioned, PHP isn't my strong suit.  I assume that there's some sort of array method to return the number of elements in it?  Also, it should be either arrayOne.length or arrayTwo.length; not just array.

Answer (score -1):

```
    foreach (array_combine($_POST['pedimento'], $_POST['observacion']) as $value => $val) {
     echo $value;
     echo $val;
}
```

what about this?

Comment: What if these 2 arrays are not equivalent to each other. Won't some values be lost in that case ?

Comment: Also, if `pedimento` has non-unique values they will be overwritten.

Answer (score -1):

```
$array1 = array("A","B","C");
$array2 = array(1,2,3);
foreach (array_combine($array1,$array2) as $first => $second) {
     echo $first." ". $second;
}
```

output:

```
A 1B 2C 3
```

Comment: What about `$array1 = array("A","B","C","B","C");` etc...?